# Is scala.Singleton pure compiler fiction?

Tags: scala, types, singleton, language-design, specifications

The [Scala Language Specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf) says under §3.2.1:

> A stable type is either a singleton
>   type or a type which is declared to be
>   a subtype of trait scala.Singleton.

I couldn't find `scala.Singleton` neither in the sources, in ScalaDoc nor in the binary jar file.

Trying on the REPL results in:

```
scala> class Foo extends Singleton
<console>:9: error: illegal inheritance from final trait Singleton
       class Foo extends Singleton
                         ^
<console>:9: error: illegal inheritance; superclass Any
 is not a subclass of the superclass Object
 of the mixin trait ScalaObject
       class Foo extends Singleton
                 ^
```

Where does `scala.Singelton` live and what's its purpose?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally found something on this:

> The type Singleton is essentially an
>   encoding trick for existentials  with
>   values. I.e.

```
T forSome { val x: T }
```

> is turned into

```
[x.type := X] T forSome { type X <:T with Singleton }
```

Source: http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/scala-Singleton-td1940630.html