# Meaning of the Singleton word in Scala

Tags: scala

I have an understanding of what Singleton objects are, but perusing a library i came across something that confused me: mixing in `Singleton`

```
trait Foo[A <: Bar with Singleton]
```

I cant seem to find info on what this means. A is a subtype of Bar-with-Singleton-access? What does mixing in Singleton provide?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a related question here: [Is scala.Singleton pure compiler fiction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6118038/is-scala-singleton-pure-compiler-fiction)

And here: [Why do String literals conform to Scala Singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11594828/why-do-string-literals-conform-to-scala-singleton)

which might help understanding scala.Singleton

"The type Singleton is essentially an encoding trick for existentials with values. I.e.

```
T forSome { val x: T }
```

is turned into

```
[x.type := X] T forSome { type X <:T with Singleton }
```

It's not something you would generally use yourself. Although you could use Singleton to to enforce a type of a Singleton as say a parameter to a method. e.g.

```
object X
class C

def foo[T<:Singleton](singleton: T): Unit = {
  print(singleton.getClass.getName)
}

foo(X)    //This would work, outputs X$

foo(new C)    //This would not work
```

Answer (score 0):

`Singleton` is the special type which all `object`s inherit. So this means `A` can only be `SomeObject.type`, where `SomeObject` is an `object` extending `Bar`. Or `Nothing`, because it's unfortunately a subtype of anything at all.